# Growth of the Riemann–Siegel theta function

Tags: complex-analysis

The Riemann-Siegel theta function is defined by:

$ \theta(t) = arg\left(\Gamma(\frac{0.5+it}{2}) \right) - \frac{t}{2}\log{\pi}$

As in the following:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Siegel_theta_function
However the same article claims that $\theta(t)$ is increasing for $t>6.29$,  $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Indeed graphs of the function from [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Riemann-SiegelFunctions.html) confirm this.

I don't understand how the argument is being defined here. Clearly if one uses the "usual" method of defining a single valued argument by selecting an interval say $ (-\pi,\pi]$ or $(0,2\pi]$, then $\theta(t)$ is bounded above and decreasing for all $t$ above some sufficienctly large $n\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Here the argument is the imaginary part of the logarithm of the function in cause so not any particular branch of the multivalued argument for complex numbers, jumping between them at zeroes of the real or imaginary parts (function has no zeroes or poles on our domain so we can define an analytic logarithm); $\Im {\log\Gamma}$ grows like $t\log t$ vertically so here the argument grows like $\frac{t}{2}\log t$ because $\log {\frac{t}{2}}$ is about $\log t$

Answer (score 1):

*Too long for a comment.*

I had the same problem as you with that specific part of the Wikipedia page.

Fortunately, just below, they give  the asymptotic expansion
$$\theta(t)\sim\frac{t}{2}  \log \left(\frac{t}{2 \pi }\right)-\frac{t}{2}-\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{1}{48t}+\cdots$$
$$\theta'(t)\sim \frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{t}{2 \pi }\right)-\frac{1}{48 t^2}\qquad \text{and} \qquad  \theta''(t)\sim \frac{1}{2 t}+\frac{1}{24 t^3}\quad > 0 \quad \forall t>0$$

If we ignore the second term, the derivative cancels for $t=2\pi$; if we take this term into account, the minimum value is at 
$$t=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3 W\left(\frac{1}{48 \pi ^2}\right)}}\approx 6.28981$$ while the exact derivative
$$\theta'(t)=-\frac{\log (\pi )}{2}+\frac{1}{4} \left(\psi \left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{i
   t}{2}\right)+\psi \left(\frac{i t}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\right)\right)$$ cancels at $t=6.28984$